# Reading from & writing to network stream simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

```
public class twowaychat {

    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader read;
    BufferedWriter write;
    String temp, temp1;

    twowaychat() {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread("Read-Client") {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    do {

                        temp = read.readLine();

                        System.out.print(temp);
                    } while (!(temp.equals("Exit")));
                    close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Line 30 error     :" + e.toString());
                }

            }
        };
        Thread thread2 = new Thread("Write-Client") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                    do {
                        temp1 = scan.next();
                        write.write(temp1);

                    } while (!(temp.equals("Exit")));
                    close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Line 53 error     :" + e.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        try {

            server = new ServerSocket(4368);
            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected ");
            read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Line 72 error     :" + e.toString());
        }

    }

    protected void close() {
        try {
            System.out.print("Closing Connection");
            read.close();
            write.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        twowaychat obj = new twowaychat();
    }
}
```

I want to build a chatting program. So client & server can chat. I have used two threads in both client & server to read & write from & to streams respectively. But this program is not working at all just prints "Connected". My client program also follows the same structure as the above server program.
I want a program where client & server can keep sending & receiving messages till Exit is entered.

Comment: As usual. You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator when sending the message.

Comment: @user207421 I have added write.newLine() but it still doesn't work .

Comment: As it is a `BufferedWriter` you also need to call `flush()` after the newline.